# Integrals finding volume using the washer or disk method

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the region bounded by the
curves $y = 5$ and $y = x+ \frac{4}{x}$ when it is rotated about the line $y = 1$.

I try to find the volume of this solid and I know that cut-off points in $x$ are $ x=1 $ and $x=4$
and when I'm building the integral I understand that the outer radius is 4 but I'm not sure what the length of the smallest radius is.

$v= \pi \int_{1}^4 (5-1)^2 -( )^2dx$

I would like you to explain to me the length of the other radius and how to find it, is it possible that you can show me an image?

Comment: The other one is $\left(x + \frac{4}{x} - 1\right)^2$

Comment: You can draw it yourself and check. Use https://www.desmos.com/calculator